# fork and exec many different processes, and obtain results from each one

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, exec, fork

I have managed to fork and exec a different program from within my app. I'm currently working on how to wait until the process called from exec returns a result through a pipe or stdout. However, can I have a group of processes using a single fork, or do I have to fork many times and call the same program again? Can I get a PID for each different process ? I want my app to call the same program I'm currently calling many times but with different parameters: I want a group of 8 processes of the same program running and returning results via pipes. Can someone please point me to the right direction please ? I've gone through the linux.die man pages, but they are quite spartan and cryptic in their description. Is there an ebook or pdf I can find for detailed information ? Thank you!

```
pid_t pID = fork();
 if (pID == 0){
  int proc = execl(BOLDAGENT,BOLDAGENT,"-u","2","-c","walkevo.xml",NULL);
  std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}
```

For example, how can I control by PID which child (according to the parameter xml file) has obtained which result (by pipe or stdout), and thus act accordingly? Do I have to encapsulate children processes in an object, and work from there, or can I group them altogether?

Comment: Post some code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Neil: Could not stay away forever.

Comment: @Martin But  a year off (nearly) is not bad?

Comment: @Neil: I expect you to pass me by the end of the month then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One `Fork` syscall make only one new process (one PID). You should organize some data structures (e.g. array of pids, array of parent's ends of pipes, etc), do 8 fork from main program (every child will do `exec`) and then wait for childs.

After each fork() it will return you a PID of child. You can store this pid and associated information like this:

```
#define MAX_CHILD=8
pid_t pids[MAX_CHILD];
int pipe_fd[MAX_CHILD];
for(int child=0;child<MAX_CHILD;child++) {
 int pipe[2];
 /* create a pipe; save one of pipe fd to the pipe_fd[child] */
 int ret;
 ret = fork();
 if(ret) { /* parent */ 
  /* close alien half of pipe */
  pids[child] = ret; /* save the pid */
 } else { /* child */
  /* close alien half of pipe */
  /* We are child #child, exec needed program */
  exec(...);
  /* here can be no more code in the child, as `exec` will not return if there is no error! */
 }
} 

/* there you can do a `select` to wait data from several pipes; select will give you number of fd with data waiting, you can find a pid from two arrays */
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and advice. I guess you are right, I should organize them. I'll ask you what I asked Pete Wilson below, do you know how I can distinguish the children from one another by using their PID?

Comment: @Alex -- each of the children gets its own, unique PID. Think about it: it must be that way because we can't have multiple processes running around with the same PIDs. PID is the only way the OS has to identify and keep track of running jobs, right?

Comment: @Pete Wilson : Yes, as far as I understand PID is the same results obtained from "ps" right?
@osgx : thank you for your help and your code, but I still don't understand how I can manipulate children from their PID. Is there an API call I can use to obtain a specific process's PID?
To be specific, I want to wait for a children to finish, and obtain results. But I want to do that for many processes concurrently, so I need a way to distinguish them by PID.

Comment: @Alex -- that's right. "ps" shows processes by their process IDs (i.e., their PIDs) and also by their **parent-process** IDs (PPIDs).

Comment: @Alex, I need some more details about your task and your prosecces. Do you want to just get from childs the return code (then you need `wait` system call)? Or you must pass text output of child process to the parent (like bash do with `cat file | grep smthg`; then you need `pipe` syscall and `select` as it is in my sample).

Answer (score 5):

It's mind-bending at first, but you seem to grasp that, when you call fork( ):

- the calling process (the "parent") is
  essentially duplicated by the
  operating system and the duplicate process 
  becomes the "child"
  with a unique PID all its own;
- the returned value from the fork( )
  call is either: integer
  0,<sup>1</sup> meaning that the
  program receiving the 0 return is the
  "child"; or it is the non-zero integer PID
  of that forked child; and
- the new child process is entered into
  the scheduling queue for execution.
  The parent remains in the scheduling
  queue and continues to execute as
  before.

It is this ( 0 **.xor.** non-0 ) return from fork( ) that tells the program which role it's playing at this instant -- 0 returned, program is the child process; anything else returned, program is the parent process.

If the program playing the parent role wants many children, he has to fork( ) each one separately; there's no such thing as multiple children sharing a fork( ).

Intermediate results certainly can be sent via a pipe.

As for calling each child with different parameters, there's really nothing special to do: you can be sure that, when the child gets control, he will have (copies of) exactly the same variables as does the parent. So communicating parameters to the child is a matter of the parent's setting up variable values he wants the child to operate on; and then calling fork( ).

---

<sup>1</sup> More accurately: fork( ) returns a value of type `pid_t`, which these days is identical to an integer on quite a few systems.

Comment: Most examples I've seen so far and the one I'm using, establish a single fork and process. Do multiple children & processes get assigned different PID's ? The examples I've seen use PID zero for the child, and non zero for the parent. What I need is a way to establish which is child is which process to relate to output. Basically I need 8 processes easily distinguishable from one another. Any help on that please?

Comment: @Alex -- yes, each forked child get its own unique PID which is  returned to the program that called fork( ). The call to fork( ) that returns **in the child** returns the value zero -- that's how the child knows it's the child. The child then has to issue **getpid( )** to find out its own process ID. That PID -- the one returned to the child by getpid( ) -- is the same one that was returned to the parent from the fork( ) call that started the child.

Comment: Thanx, I didn't see this reply! This should help me figure out, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've worked in C/C++, but a few points:

- The Wikipedia [fork-exec page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec) provides a starting point to learn about forking and execing. Google is your friend here too.
- As osgx's answer says, fork() can only give you one subprocess, so you'll have to call it 8 times to get 8 processes and then each one will have to exec the other program.
- fork() returns the PID of the child process to the main process and 0 to the subprocess, so you should be able to do something like:

```c
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  /* exec new program here */
} else {
  /* continue with parent process stuff */
}
```